# Change text of textblock within a panoramaitem

Tags: c#, xaml

I need to use two textblock within a single panorama item. I have used a grid to implement this.
Problem is that I need to change the text of the textblock programmatically.

```
    <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Current Status">
        <Grid >
            <TextBlock x:Name="Spent" Margin="138,0,90,464" FontSize="40"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Left" Margin="138,50,90,414" FontSize="40"/>
        </Grid>
    </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

Saying:

```
    Spent.Text = Convert.ToString(total_spent);
    Left.Text = Convert.ToString(total_left);
```

in the c# file gives an error.

Please tell me how to change the text of the individual textblocks :)

P.S:
I am an absolute beginner and almost completely self taught, so a simple answer will be useful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Text` property of the TextBlock to get/set the Text.

From MSDN : [`TextBlock.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets the text contents of a TextBlock.

Try This:

```
Spent.Text = Convert.ToString(total_spent.Text);
Left.Text = Convert.ToString(total_left.Text);
```